# Subset a 2D array by a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to use a 2D array to subset another 2D array(they have the same length), for example:

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.array([[0.33, 0.67], [0.67, 0.33]])
index = np.array([[1], [0]])
```

What I want is something like this:

```
In[91]: np.array([tmp[i][index[i]] for i in range(len(index))])

Out[91]: 
array([[ 0.67],
       [ 0.67]])
```

It works but, is there a smarter/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Quick check: are you going to have any cases where `index.shape[1] != 1`? If so, should those also produce a result equivalent to what your existing expression does with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the indices of the rows using `shape()` of your `index` array and the `inedx` itself as the the columns, then use a simple indexing to get the intended items:

```
>>> tmp[(np.array(index.shape[::-1])-1)[:,None], index]
array([[ 0.67],
       [ 0.67]])
```